# Set date values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

I created a form for the users to insert a date (days/months) and I need to disable the possibility to insert incoherent values such as for the month the maximum value would be **12** and for the days the maximum **31**, I want to disable the possibility to insert numbers higher than that.

**This is the form**

```
 <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <label for="dtDateFrom">From Day/Month</label>
            <input type="text" name="datefrom" id="dtDateFrom"  value="%dtDateFrom%"/>
        </div>
```

**And this is the mask I used to make it 4 digits long and separated with `a/`**

```
function maskFormatterForData(val) {
    $(val).mask("ZZ / ZZ", {
        translation: {
            'Z': {
                pattern: /[0-9]/,
                optional: true
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Using regular expression for both days and months are not possible because they have different range of values. You need a javascript function to make the check

Comment: Ok, you know how to do it?

Comment: To get proper answers, add a working code snippet reproducing the issue, not just code fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the alerts with action to show message:

```js
$("#dtDateFrom").on("change", function(){
  var result = $(this).val().split("/");
  
  if(result.length == 2){
    if(result[0] >= 1 && result[0] <= 12 && result[1] >= 1 &&  result[1] <= 12){
      alert("Valid entry");
    }
    else{
      alert("Please enter the field in format Day/Month");
    }
  }
  else{
    alert("Please enter the field in format Day/Month");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <label for="dtDateFrom">From Day/Month</label>
            <input type="text" name="dtDateFrom" id="dtDateFrom" />
        </div>
```